# Data cut in SQL Table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a table with basic Data (Last Name, First Name, ID..)

I have created the table but the complete name doesn't appear in the table, for example:

```
Last Name       First Name    
Gonzalez Rami   Margarita
```

Rami should be Ramirez. I have declared Last Name as `longtext`. How do I see the complete Last Name in the table or ensure that is not cut?

Comment: First, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: are you using `mySQL` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use varchar if you want to get good performance for indexing and searching.

such as:

```
Last_Name varchar(30),
```

the thirty is how many characters you will allow in the field.  Set it to what number you want under the max(which escapes me at the moment but is somewhere beyond 60 for varchar)  Excess will be automatically cut off.

Comment: I did that with varchar(30), varchar(40) and varchar(50). But it still cut, you know the reason?

Comment: U would have to show the code you used to build the table.

Comment: @MargaritaGonzalez Did you figure it out? What did you do to get the rest of the name to display?